# AngularJS - autocomplete with $http requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete

I have an application in AngularJS and I want to implement an autocomplete input for a certain list of programs.

My problem is that I have lots of programs in my database and I don't want to load them all when the page loads. Instead I load pages and have a button that loads the next page when clicked.

```
scope.loadPrograms = function() {
    Programs.getPage($scope.page)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.allprograms.push.apply($scope.allprograms, data.campaigns);
            $scope.page++;
            if(data.pagination.pages < $scope.page) {
                $scope.page = -1;
            } 
        })
        .error(function(data){
            alert('There has been an error. Please try again later!');
        });
}
```

and the button

```
<md-button ng-click="loadPrograms()" ng-show="page != -1">Load more data</md-button>
```

So this approach makes me do a request everytime I write/delete a letter in the autocomplete input, given the fact that I don't have all the program loaded on `$scope`. Is it ok to make so many request? Is there another approach?

Thanks.

### EDIT

Ok so now I put a delay on the autocomplete, but the method doesn't work anymore.

```
                // Search for programs
                scope.querySearch = function(query) {
                    if (typeof pauseMonitor !== 'undefined') {
                        $timeout.cancel(pauseMonitor); 
                    }

                    pauseMonitor = $timeout(function() {
                        var results = query ? scope.allprograms.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : [];
                        return results;
                    }, 250);

                };

                // Create filter function for a query string
                function createFilterFor(query) {
                  var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);
                  return function filterFn(programs) {
                    return (programs.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowercaseQuery) != -1);
                  };
                };
```

It enters in the `createFilterFor` method, finds a good match but doesn't show it anymore.

Comment: You can also try this. http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos

Comment: I see that it only adds tags. I want to have the autocomplete function..

Comment: Have you checked 'Autocomplete with $resource' demo of that directive.

Comment: The update is about a completely different context than the original question.

Comment: Why? Sorry but I am learning Angular and I don't see that i'm missing

Comment: You shouldn't try to get a single post solving all your project. One question should be around a single context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to retrieve a set of words for the purpose of auto completion from a large database, one simple trick is to use `$timeout` with some time threshold which can detect the pauses of the user typing.

The idea is to prevent a request being generated for every key. You look for a pause in the user typing pattern and make your request there for the letters typed. This is a simple implementation of this idea in your key handler.

```
function processInput(input) {

     if (typeof pauseMonitor !== 'undefined') {
       $timeout.cancel(pauseMonitor); 


     pauseMonitor = $timeout(function() {
       //make your request here 
     }, 250);
}
```

Comment: this a really good idea! but now I have a problem, I will post it up

Comment: Your new problem has nothing to do with *autocomplete with $http request*. One post should solve a specific problem - not all the problems come in a project.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ng-model-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)
you can set a `debounce time` and some other interesting things.

```
ng-model-options="{ debounce: '1000' }"
```

Above line means the input value will be updated in the model after 1 sec